Configuring Gradle (Java Project) to use KeyStore/TrustStore for only one maven repository (Sonatype Nexus Repository 3)
I have successfully set up Sonatype Nexus Repository 3 on my server with SSL configured using KeyStore/TrustStore.
I developed some Java libraries (using Gradle) to test the publication to the repository.
After several attempts, I managed to publish the library by configuring Gradle like this:
File: gradle.properties
MyNexusUsername=<user>
MyNexusPassword=<pwd>

systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=nexus/keystore.jks
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<mypw>

File: build.gradle (repositories)
maven {
   name = 'MyNexus'
   credentials(PasswordCredentials)
   url = uri('https://myurl/repository/repo-name/')
}

Now, I am working on another Java project and I want to use the library from my Nexus repository.
When I use the same configuration, the library is retrieved correctly from the repository.
However, the problem arises when I try to fetch other necessary libraries from Maven Central.
Gradle fails to retrieve them.
I am wondering, how can I configure Gradle so that the KeyStore/TrustStore (the .jks files) are applied only to my Nexus repository and not globally?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

As far as I know you can not specify a separate trust store per repository. My recommendation is to copy the JDK default trust store (cacerts) and import your certificate in the copy. That way the trust store will have the default certificates to connect with Maven Central and other sites with public certificates from well known CAs plus your own server.
The cacerts file is located in JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts.
To import a certificate you could use a command like:
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file mycert.crt -keystore mycacertscopy.jks

